# Mikrotik Script runs perfectly in terminal but doesn't run when placed in scripts

Tags: scripting, mikrotik

I am trying to add a script to the list in order to schedule it to run it on interval base but it's not working when I place it in scripts and works perfectly when I manually execute the script in Terminal in Mikrotik.
I have tried both these version of script as :

The `\n /r/` Script Version:

```
{\r\
\n:global NSM2 [/ip neighbor find mac-address="68:72:51:34:AA:03"];/r/
\n:foreach i in=$NSM2 do={/r/
\n:global nsm2tx [/ip neighbor get $i address];/r/
\n}/r/
\n/ip firewall nat set 11 to-address=$nsm2tx/r/
\n:global NSM2 [/ip neighbor find mac-address="68:72:51:32:11:60"];/r/
\n:foreach i in=$NSM2 do={/r/
\n:global nsm2rx [/ip neighbor get $i address];/r/
\n}/r/
\n/ip firewall nat set 10 to-addresses=$nsm2rx/r/
\n}
```

The Normal Version :

```
:global NSM2 [/ip neighbor find mac-address="68:72:51:34:AA:03"];
:foreach i in=$NSM2 do={
:global nsm2tx [/ip neighbor get $i address];
}
/ip firewall nat set 11 to-address=$nsm2tx

:global NSM2 [/ip neighbor find mac-address="68:72:51:32:11:60"];
:foreach i in=$NSM2 do={
:global nsm2rx [/ip neighbor get $i address];
}
/ip firewall nat set 10 to-addresses=$nsm2rx
```

But none of these works when placed in scripts and then click on run button or when schedule runs..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind your script is correct but the syntax wasn't; Mikrotik scripting language is very picky, so i reviewed it, here is a working version:

```
:local nsm2tx [/ip neighbor get [find mac-address="68:72:51:34:AA:03"] address];
/ip firewall nat set 10 to-addresses="$nsm2tx"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11185835)

Comment: My answer provides a solution to his problem, i just corrected and rephrased his script.... so i don't understand your remark

Comment: Now that details are added, it is effectively an answer. Before that was only a piece of code placed there

Comment: @BenoitPHILIPPON : Thanks for correcting my script..!